# Scale text size in FPDF

Tags: fpdf

I'm using FPDF and I have a little problem:
I am printing dynamic text in a line that have a maximum width. The text has a maximum height and, when the text have more width that the line, I'm decreasing the font size of the text until it fits to the line.

It works fine, but I want to know if I could decrease only the text width, scaling it and mantaining the height that I declared at the beginning. I've read the documentation and searched for a solution but I didn't find anything related to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an add-on to scale the text and it works great:

http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/62/

Instead of using the Cell() function, I use the CellFitScale() function and it scales automatically only the width of the text.